# displaying arraylist into a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, arraylist, datatable

I have an arraylist which stores values when a user does an action during runtime. Now im trying to display these values into a datagridview . so what im doing is adding the arraylist items into a datatable and then binding the datatable to the Gridview. but what is being displayed in the datagrid is not the values of the arraylist. here is my code .please help or can anyone direct me to how else this could be done..Thanks in advance

```
         foreach (Class1 aa in ds) 
         {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(aa.id + "_" + aa.shape + "_" + aa.color);

                  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                  dt.Columns.Add("Shape");
                  dt.Columns.Add("Colour");
                  for (int i = 0; i < ds.Count; i++)
                  {
                    dt.Rows.Add(ds);
                      dt.Rows[i]["Shape"] = ds[i].ToString();
                      dt.Rows[i]["Colour"] = ds[i].ToString();
                      dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
                 }
                 dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set the datasource outside the loops

Comment: @Sybren still the same :(

Comment: Is `ds` your arraylist ? And also if you can provide what output you are receiving. That might help.

Comment: @iCoder yes ds is my arraylist..the datagridview instead displays the name of the project and the name of the class which contains the properties that i want to be displayed

Comment: Try replacing `ds[i].ToString()` with `aa.shape` and `aa.color`.

Comment: @iCoder okay it does display the shape and colour but with every addition of item to the grid , the previous entry gets deleted and also there is a repetition. ( so for example the first time entry will be displayed once, second time entry will be displayed twice and so on)

Comment: Try setting `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` outside the `for` loop. Exactly above `dataGridView1.Refresh();` and check how it displays.

Comment: @iCoder nope still the same :(

Comment: Check the answer that I just posted. Maybe that could help.

Comment: @iCoder thank you for trying to help me solve this..i tried your solution. still the same.i have no idea where im going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try creating a `DataTable` and then adding the required `DataRows` to it like this :

```
foreach (Class1 aa in ds) 
     {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(aa.id + "_" + aa.shape + "_" + aa.color);

              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
              dt.Columns.Add("Shape");
              dt.Columns.Add("Colour");
              for (int i = 0; i < ds.Count; i++)
              {
                  DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
                  dRow["Shape"] = aa.shape;
                  dRow["Colour"] = aa.color;
                  dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
             }
             dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
             dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.